# Can someone explain how this Clang argument working?

Tags: clang, clang++, llvm-clang

While searching Google, I discovered that this command below can show the `clang` default include path, but how does it work? I've checked help page and know the meaning of each argument, but I can't understand how these arguments work together, especially the `-` between `c++` and `-v`.

```
clang++ -E -x c++ - -v < /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clang++` is the name of the program to run.

`-E` is an option telling clang to stop after preprocessing (i.e. it won't run the actual compiler or linker, just the preprocessor).

`-x c++` is a language override option. It tells clang that the input file should be interpreted as C++ source code (the default behavior is to detect the file type from the extension, such as `.cpp` or `.o`).

`-v` means "verbose", I think. It tells clang to print extra information during compilation.

`-` is not an option; it's the name of the input file. As with many other tools, an input filename of `-` tells clang to read from its standard input instead.

Finally `< /dev/null` is an I/O redirection. It tells the shell to connect clang's standard input to `/dev/null` (effectively an empty file).

The last two parts are a bit roundabout: Instead of telling clang to read from stdin and redirecting stdin to `/dev/null`, we could've just told clang to read from `/dev/null` directly:

```
clang++ -E -x c++ -v /dev/null
```

Anyway, the point is to preprocess (`-E`) an empty file (`/dev/null`) as if it were C++ code (`-x c++`).

Comment: thanks for this answer, now i understand this command :) but still confused why it can print the include path? i mean why do a preprocessor on the empty file(i test it on hello world.c, it also give me the include path ,but with other information like "/usr/include/_stdio.h 2 3 4") can make clang  show the path? Is this some kind of clang log?